# Why is getWindowImageRect in OpenCV for Windows does not return the expected value?

Tags: opencv

I was trying to make a fullscreen window in OpenCV and the functions provided in OpenCV are working except there is a white edge in the left border and top border. After spending time in investigating the code in OpenCV, I found out that the function getWindowImageRect is somehow returning a value that is 1px more in x, y and 1px less in width and height than the function that I have wrote.

Okay, and here is the question. Why are the two functions returning different values?

Here is the code I have found in OpenCV:

```
CvRect cvGetWindowRect_W32(const char* name)
{
    CvRect result = cvRect(-1, -1, -1, -1);

    CV_FUNCNAME( "cvGetWindowRect_W32" );

    __BEGIN__;

    CvWindow* window;

    if (!name)
        CV_ERROR( CV_StsNullPtr, "NULL name string" );
    window = icvFindWindowByName( name );
    if (!window)
        EXIT; // keep silence here

    RECT rect;
    GetClientRect(window->hwnd, &rect);
    {
    POINT pt = {rect.left, rect.top};
    ClientToScreen(window->hwnd, &pt);
    result = cvRect(pt.x, pt.y, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top);
    }
    __END__;
    return result;
}
```

This is the code that I have wrote in Python, which I thought will give me the same result:

```
def getWindowRect(name)
    hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, name)
    rect_l, rect_t, rect_r, rect_b = win32gui.GetClientRect(hwnd)
    pt_x, pt_y = win32gui.ClientToScreen(hwnd, (rect_l, rect_t))
    result = (pt_x, pt_y, rect_r - rect_l, rect_b - rect_t)
    return result
```

The result of using the two above functions give me output like this:

```
(1, 1, 2559, 1439)
(0, 0, 2560, 1440)
```

So I wonder if any one can tell me why is this happening?

Note that the test is performed under Windows 10.

Comment: The problem is there are 2 windows involved -- an outer "frame" which has the title set, and an inner unnamed window which renders the image. The OpenCV function gives you the size of the inner window, whereas your code works with the outer "frame". (You can use Spy++ to see this nicely)

Comment: I wonder which part of the code indicates that OpenCV is finding the inner frame instead of the outer frame? Is it the part "icvFindWindowByName( name )" is actually giving the inner frame window? If that is the case, is it true that OpenCV does not allow user to modify the outer frame (e.g. remove the outer frame border) at all?

Comment: Ya, `icvFindWindowByName` searches through an internal data structure and returns as [`CvWindow`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.4.2/modules/highgui/src/window_w32.cpp#L150) instance. This object holds handles to both the OS windows mentioned (`frame` and `hwnd` members). [This](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.4.2/modules/highgui/src/window_w32.cpp#L826) is where those values are assigned when creating a named window (you can find the `CreateWindow`s few dozen lines above that).

Comment: **NOTE:** this "gutter" (as it was called in source) [was](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/commit/0c0cf8b19f4f4a5ab1563e744e7451f3487308b1) [removed](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/commit/beba82b22be0ce1205c686602d5f71c4b846f51d) in 2021. this 1-pixel discrepancy should not be there anymore.